# jQuery / Javascript method to get title of current page, match it to a stringa, assign class to that specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok lets say I have:

```
<title>Monkey</title>
```

and then some navigation:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li>
        <a href=#">Monkey</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As the site loads, the title of the page gets stored as a variable, then I want the string to match anything within #navigation, in this case it is Monkey. After finding the string of text it then assigns a class:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li class="current">
        <a href="#">Monkey</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Are there any examples people can refer me to?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('#navigation a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == document.title;
}).closest('li').addClass('current');
```